# Iterate over nested dictionary without nested for loops

Tags: python

If I am having a nested dictionary (similar to this examples dict) and and I want to loop through it, is there a better way with e.g. itertools than this:

```py
foo = {
    'key1': [
        {
            'key2': [
                {
                    'info2' : 'Info A',
                    'key3': [
                        {
                            'key_a': 'A',
                            'key_b': 'B'
                        },
                        {
                            'key_a': 'A2',
                            'key_b': 'B'
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]}

for keys1 in foo['key1']:
    for keys2s in keys1['key2']:
        for keys3 in keys2s['key3']:
            print(keys2s['info2'])
            print(keys3['key_a'])
```

***Output***

```
Info A
A
Info A
A2
```

Comment: Would recursion be an option?

Comment: How do you decide which valus to print ?

Comment: print is not the operation I want to do with the values, its basically to show which data I need

Comment: @MK1986 Why are you printing Info A twice?  It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Printing is just an example operation, it could also be calling a func foo( keys2s['info2'],  keys3['key_a'])